# Google Analytics & Adwords delayed javascript link to App Store ignored?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I'm trying to measure conversion for both my Google Adwords campaign and normal traffic going to the App Store. Previously I had a link "/app_store/" on my page that would load, wait 1 second and then continue to the app store.

I found a more elegant solution somewhere using Javascript. For adwords it loads a pixel image and for analytics it calls a Google Javascript function, pauses for a fraction of a second and then follows the link.

Unfortunately it's not working for me. Google Analytics and Google Adsense don't see anyone going to the App Store (not even myself).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-18180332-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
    try{
        // Google Analytics
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-18180332-1");
        pageTracker._trackEvent(category, action);

        // Google Adwords
        var image = new Image(1, 1);
        image.src = "http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1046551421/?value=$8&amp;label=zqrfCMWh0QEQ_baE8wM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"
        setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)

    } catch(err) {}
}
</script>
```

And for the link:

```
<a href="http://itunes.apple.com/ae/app/isimplifiedchinese/id377690407?mt=8"
onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'http://itunes.apple.com/ae/app/isimplifiedchinese/id377690407?mt=8');return false;">
<img alt="Appstore" src="images/appstore.png"></a>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update 23:13**
I noticed that if the delay is 100ms, the following error flashes by (it took me a while to time the screenshot).

[image: Failed to load resource]

I only tested this with Erwan's suggestion; not sure if it also happened in the old version. The error seems to go away for longer delays; I set it to 300ms to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent the click action (browse to the link) from beeing executed until you record it.
On the onclick attribute add a "return false":

```
onclick="recordOutboundLink(params);return false;"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using "return false;" (it's a bit hidden, just scroll all the way to the right)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get mine to work with the `_gaq.push();`

instead of:

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-18180332-1");
pageTracker._trackEvent(category, action);
```

do:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action]);
```

so instead of getting the pageTracker again since the _gaq has already been initialized when the page started. simply use the _gaq to push the event tracker.  Also, keep in mind, google analytics does not update real time and more often than not it doesn't gets updated for 48 hours.

Comment: About 48 hours ago, I moved the `setTimeout` line
from between the Google Analytics and Google Adwords code to below both. So that change might not have been reflected in the data yet.
Otherwise it's been live for weeks.

I just implemented your suggestion; let's see how it goes.

Comment: i'll retract comment about the _gat maybe ga.js wasn't fully loaded when i do the `console.log(_gat)` on my test.  However, your `console.log(_gaq);` should return an array.  go to your google analytics account and pick your site.  Go to edit and then on top right yo ushoudl see check status click on that and see if your trackign is working.

Comment: @SjorsProvoost did you manage to figure out the exact error that was causing it?

Comment: not yet, will look at it again in the next few weeks and let you know

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the script is redirecting before the GA code has finished running. You could try placing it onto the gaq so it is guaranteed to run after the rest of the code. Your function might then look like this:

```
function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
    // Google Analytics
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action]);

    // Google Adwords
    _gaq.push(function() {
    var image = new Image(1, 1);
    image.src = "http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1046551421/?value=$8&amp;label=zqrfCMWh0QEQ_baE8wM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0";
    });
    _gaq.push(function() {setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100);});
}
```

I haven't tested it out but it's similar to things I've tried before.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I just implemented it and I'll let you know if it worked.